# How to delete rows from tables with foreign keys in SAP ASE Sybase 16

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to perform a row deletion from a table employee that has a primary key set on 'emp_id' column and is referenced by other tables with their foreign keys. Sybase does not allow me to perform the deletion. The example msg back is :

Dependent foreign key constraint violation in a referential integrity constraint. dbname =  'giraffe', table name = 'branch', constraint name = 'client_800002850'.
Command has been aborted.

With MySQL it is possible to easily make this kind of deletion if you specifiy foreign keys with ON DELETE clause, but this is not supported by Sybase. The only optional clause for foreign keys in this RDBMS is 'MATCH FULL'

How can one delete rows or set values to NULL in Sybase if there are foreign keys set up ? I am a total newbie in t-sql and DBA. to my understanding, having the db schema such as this, it would require not having the foreign keys at all or am I missing something ? Maybe this schema is MySQL specific and it should be coded differently to meet Sybase t-sql standards ?

here is the DDL. link to the course - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXV3zeQKqGY

===========================

```
    CREATE TABLE employee (
      emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
      first_name VARCHAR(40),
      last_name VARCHAR(40),
      birth_day DATE,
      sex VARCHAR(1),
      salary INT,
      super_id INT,
      branch_id INT
    );

    CREATE TABLE branch (
      branch_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
      branch_name VARCHAR(40),
      mgr_id INT,
      mgr_start_date DATE,
      FOREIGN KEY(mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    );

    ALTER TABLE employee
    ADD FOREIGN KEY(branch_id)
    REFERENCES branch(branch_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL;

    ALTER TABLE employee
    ADD FOREIGN KEY(super_id)
    REFERENCES employee(emp_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL;

    CREATE TABLE client (
      client_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
      client_name VARCHAR(40),
      branch_id INT,
      FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id) ON DELETE SET NULL
    );

    CREATE TABLE works_with (
      emp_id INT,
      client_id INT,
      total_sales INT,
      PRIMARY KEY(emp_id, client_id),
      FOREIGN KEY(emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
      FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    );

    CREATE TABLE branch_supplier (
      branch_id INT,
      supplier_name VARCHAR(40),
      supply_type VARCHAR(40),
      PRIMARY KEY(branch_id, supplier_name),
      FOREIGN KEY(branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id)
```

Here is a list of constraints on this 'employee' table

- branch_1008003591                        branch FOREIGN KEY (mgr_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)                                                                                                Jun 18 2019 11:58AM
- employee_880003135                       employee FOREIGN KEY (branch_id) REFERENCES branch(branch_id)                                                                                          Jun 18 2019 10:44AM
- works_with_848003021                     works_with FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES employee(emp_id)                                                                                            Jun 17 2019  7:26PM
- employee_752002679                       employee FOREIGN KEY (super_id) SELF REFERENCES employee(emp_id)                                                                                       Jun 17 2019  7:24PM
- employee_960003420                       employee FOREIGN KEY (super_id) SELF REFERENCES employee(emp_id) MATCH FULL                                                                            Jun 18 2019 11:17AM
- employee_6720023941                      PRIMARY KEY INDEX ( emp_id) : CLUSTERED, FOREIGN REFERENCE

I want to perform the following DML:

```
DELETE from dbo.employee
WHERE employee.emp_id = 102
```

In that MySQL course the subsequent automatic action would have been setting the branch.mgr_id value from 102 to NULL provided that the foreign key for 'branch' table had been set with ON DELETE SET NULL clause.

I tried setting up branch.mgr_id to NULL since it's not the PK for the table but obviously it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete a primary-key row, delete corresponding foreign-key rows in dependent tables. This preserves referential integrity by ensuring that detail rows are removed when their master row is deleted. If you do not delete the corresponding rows in the dependent tables, you may end up with a database with detail rows that cannot be retrieved or identified. To properly delete the dependent foreign-key rows, use a trigger that performs a cascading delete.

When a delete statement on titles is executed, one or more rows are removed from the titles table and are added to deleted.
A trigger can check the dependent tables—titleauthor, salesdetail, and roysched—to see if they have any rows with a title_id that matches the title_ids removed from titles and is now stored in the deleted table. If the trigger finds any such rows, it removes them.

```
create trigger delcascadetrig 
on titles 
for delete 
as 
delete titleauthor 
from titleauthor, deleted 
where titleauthor.title_id = deleted.title_id 
/* Remove titleauthor rows that match deleted
** (titles) rows.*/
delete salesdetail 
from salesdetail, deleted 
where salesdetail.title_id = deleted.title_id 
/* Remove salesdetail rows that match deleted
** (titles) rows.*/ 
delete roysched 
from roysched, deleted 
where roysched.title_id = deleted.title_id 
/* Remove roysched rows that match deleted
** (titles) rows.*/
```

source:-

"http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612501571.html"

Comment: Hey Ankush. Indeed triggers cover the referential integrity in sybase. This is it's counterpart for ON DELETE primary key parameter in mysql. Not convenient but it works

Comment: if it works then please accept or like the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is that you would update the dependent tables below before you delete the main row to remove the dependencies - leaving a foreign key column which was previously required for your data model as null in the target table (IMO anyway) is bad practice. In your example that employee has created data such as branch data which is linked to that employee - surely you wouldn't that just being back to null as this could seriously impact things like reporting per branch which use inner joins or grouping based on those IDs and doesn't account for an employee ID being null.

You can add a deletion trigger which would do the update to the dependent data if instead this was a business requirement as similar to this example:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X15877.htm